# Message Headers - X-SEF-Processed

Tags: email

I'm just trying to work out why there has been a delay on an incoming email and I have been checking the headers, and was puzzled by this line:

```
X-SEF-Processed: 6_1_0_100__2009_08_25_21_23_08
```

Am I right to assume that the `21_23_08` part is actually the time, and that this is the time it left the senders system?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

/Karmik

Comment: I have to admit I am curious myself. I can't find a reference to it in any of the RFC documents.

Comment: X- headers are for user defined extensions (see RFC822) so that there isn't a namespace collision with defined headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually relates to the Surfcontrol email software that scanned the email in question.

Format is :-

X-SEF-Processed:  Surfcontrol / Websense version, Date and Time.

Comment: Since I got no other answers I assumed this to be the case. It tied in with the info I already new from our MessageLabs interface (i.e. time it hit our mail server).